# Persist MethodInfo as property

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I am creating a custom BindingSource and would like to persist a MethodInfo as a private field.
The problem, in code:

```
public class MyBindingSource : BindingSource
{

    private MethodInfo MyMethod= null;

    protected override void OnBindingComplete(BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
         this.MyMethod = GetMyMethod();
         //MyMethod is not null here
    }

    void UseMyMethod (object value)
    {
        MyMethod.Invoke(SomeObject, new object[] { value });
        //MyMethod is null here, exception thrown.
    }

}
```

I successfully store the MethodInfo, however, when i try to use it, it ends up being null.
No special constructor is being called (overriding the field).
OnBindingComplete is not called twice.
Nothing seems to imply that something else is setting it to null.

Comment: Are you calling `UseMyMethod` before `OnBindingComplete` is called?

Comment: Are the calls to `UseMyMethod` and `OnBindingComplete` concurrent, i.e., are you missing a `lock`?

Comment: Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you calling `UseMyMethod` on a different `MyBindingSource` instance than the instance on which `OnBindingComplete` is called?

Comment: Although it seems as I am calling UseMyMethod before OnBindingComplete is called. Not intentionally.

Comment: I am using multiple instances of MyBindingSource. I set a breakpoint after `GetMyMethod` null check, and on every possible constructor of the `MyBindingSource`. The breakpoints never hit (after the inital OnBindingComplete and constructor of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are accessing `UseMethod` before `OnBindingComplete`

But in any case, to prevent this, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyBindingSource : BindingSource
{
    private MethodInfo _myMethod = null;

    private MethodInfo MyMethod
    {
        get
        {
            if(_myMethod != null) return _myMethod;

            _myMethod = GetMyMethod();
            return _myMethod;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingComplete(BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void UseMyMethod (object value)
    {
        MyMethod.Invoke(SomeObject, new object[] { value });
    }
}
```

Comment: I never did find the reason why it was set to null, but this approach works.